# Getting HttpWebRequest POST error

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

I don't know what is wrong since this code works amazing for me every time, but for an single website it give me an error called `NullReferenceException was undhandled` at `mainCookie.Add(postResponse.Cookies)` line.

Here is the code:

```
Dim mainCookie As CookieContainer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim postData As String = "login=login&username=" & UserText.Text & "&password=" & PassText.Text & "&login=Login"
    Dim bytes() As Byte = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://website.com/login.php")
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = mainCookie
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "http://website.com/"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"
    postReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Dim postStream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    postStream.Close()
    Dim postResponse As HttpWebResponse
    postResponse = postReq.GetResponse()
    mainCookie.Add(postResponse.Cookies)
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(postResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strSource As String = reader.ReadToEnd
    If strSource.Contains("Welcome") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful")
        TextBox1.Text = strSource
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
        TextBox1.Text = strSource
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Obviously, it is either your line `postResponse = postReq.GetResponse()` doesn't set `postResonse` variable to intance. Or `(postResponse.Cookies` is `null`. Please see here [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look.